# Impute missing data in multivariate time series

Tags: r, time-series, na, imputation

I have a problem where I have to predict the sales of 4000 products in 3 months for a certain store. Within the 4000 time series I have many null values and especially many continuous periods of time, for example, a product with 3 months in a row of null values. Can someone tell me some technique to impute these values? I had seen the package in R called **mtsdi** but I do not understand how it works, if someone has an example I would appreciate it.

Another method I had thought of was to interpolate but having many continuous periods of nulls I don't know if it will work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a correlation between the various products? If the products are anyway not really correlated, you can use univariate time series imputation algorithms, which only look at inter-time correlations. (e.g. the interpolation you suggested - but there are also more advanced ones, which also account for seasonality).

The **imputeTS** package offers multiple functions here. (seasonal decomposed interpolation - na_seadec() for example). [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/Cheat_Sheet_imputeTS.pdf) is a nice intro with all functions.

```
library("imputeTS")
na_seadec(yourData)
```

Code would look as easy as this example.

But as you correctly assume - the longer the NA gap is, the harder it gets to produce reasonable imputations just by looking a inter-time correlations of one variable. 3 months continuously NA is a lot.

So if there is a some correlation between your products/variables it makes sense to actually use this.

For using **mtsdi** just look at the example provided in the package documentation:

```
library(mtsdi)
data(miss)
f <- ~c31+c32+c33+c34+c35
i <- mnimput(formula = f, dataset = miss, eps = 1e-3, ts = TRUE, method = "spline", sp.control = list(df=c(7,7,7,7,7)))
summary(i)
```

This would be the parameters from the example:

```
> formula - formula indicating the missing data frame, for instance, ~X1+X2+X3+...+Xp
> dataset - data with missing values to be imputated
> eps - stop criterion
> ts  - logical. TRUE if is time series
> method - method for univariate time series filtering. It may be smooth, gam or arima. See Details
> sp.control - list for Spline smooth control. See Details
```

But I am not too convinced from the mtsdi package and methodology. Seems not very mature to me.

If there is a inter-variable correlation I would rather use the **mice** package. This is for cross-sectional data, but you can model time aspects partially as additional variables. (e.g. add lag and lead variables)